# Efficient solution to object detection algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to implement this paper 'Salient Object detection by composition' here is the link: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/yichenw/iccv11_salientobjectdetection.pdf

I have implemented the algorithm but it takes a long time to execute and display the output. I'm using 4 for loops in the code(Using for loops is the only way I could think of to implement this algorithm.) I have searched online for MATLAB code, but couldn't find anything. So can anyone please suggest any faster way to implement the algorithm. Also in the paper they(the authors) say that they have implemented the code using MATLAB and it runs quickly. So there definitely is a way to write the code more efficiently.

I appreciate any hint or code to execute this algorithm efficiently.

```
clc
clear all
close all

%%instructions to run segment.cpp
%to run this code
%we need an output image
%segment sigma K min input output
%sigma: used for gaussian smoothing of the image 
%K: scale of observation; larger K means larger components in segmentation
%min: minimum component size enforced by post processing

%%
%calculating composition cost for each segment
I_org = imread('segment\1.ppm');
I = imread('segment\output1.ppm');
[rows,cols,dims] = size(I);
pixels = zeros(rows*cols,dims);
red_channel = I(:,:,1);
green_channel = I(:,:,2);
blue_channel = I(:,:,3);
[unique_pixels,count_pixels] = countPixels(I);
no_segments = size(count_pixels,1);
area_segments = count_pixels ./ (rows * cols);
appearance_distance = zeros(no_segments,no_segments);
spatial_distance = zeros(no_segments,no_segments);
thresh = multithresh(I_org,11);
thresh_values = [0 thresh];
for i = 1:no_segments    
    leave_pixel = unique_pixels(i,:);
    mask_image = ((I(:,:,1) == leave_pixel(1)) & (I(:,:,2) == leave_pixel(2)) & (I(:,:,3) == leave_pixel(3)));
    I_i(:,:,1) = I_org(:,:,1) .* uint8((mask_image));
    I_i(:,:,2) = I_org(:,:,2) .* uint8((mask_image));
    I_i(:,:,3) = I_org(:,:,3) .* uint8((mask_image));
    LAB_trans = makecform('srgb2lab');
    I_i_LAB = applycform(I_i,LAB_trans);
    L_i_LAB = imhist(I_i_LAB(:,:,1));
    A_i_LAB = imhist(I_i_LAB(:,:,2));
    B_i_LAB = imhist(I_i_LAB(:,:,3));
    for j = i:no_segments
        leave_pixel = unique_pixels(j,:);
        mask_image = ((I(:,:,1) == leave_pixel(1)) & (I(:,:,2) == leave_pixel(2)) & (I(:,:,3) == leave_pixel(3)));
        I_j(:,:,1) = I_org(:,:,1) .* uint8((mask_image));
        I_j(:,:,2) = I_org(:,:,2) .* uint8((mask_image));
        I_j(:,:,3) = I_org(:,:,3) .* uint8((mask_image));
        I_j_LAB = applycform(I_j,LAB_trans);
        L_j_LAB = imhist(I_j_LAB(:,:,1));
        A_j_LAB = imhist(I_j_LAB(:,:,2));
        B_j_LAB = imhist(I_j_LAB(:,:,3));
        appearance_distance(i,j) = sum(min(L_i_LAB,L_j_LAB) + min(A_i_LAB,A_j_LAB) + min(B_i_LAB,B_j_LAB));
        spatial_distance(i,j) = ModHausdorffDist(I_i,I_j) / max(rows,cols);
    end
end
spatial_distance = spatial_distance ./ max(max(spatial_distance));
max_apperance_distance = max(max(appearance_distance));
composition_cost = ((1 - spatial_distance) .* appearance_distance) + (spatial_distance * max_apperance_distance);
%%  
%input parameters for computation
window_size = 9; %rows and colums are considered to be same
window = ones(window_size);
additional_elements = (window_size - 1)/2;
I_temp(:,:,1) =     [zeros(additional_elements,cols);I(:,:,1);zeros(additional_elements,cols)];
I_new(:,:,1) = [zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)     I_temp(:,:,1) zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)];
I_temp(:,:,2) = [zeros(additional_elements,cols);I(:,:,2);zeros(additional_elements,cols)];
I_new(:,:,2) = [zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)     I_temp(:,:,2) zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)];
I_temp(:,:,3) = [zeros(additional_elements,cols);I(:,:,3);zeros(additional_elements,cols)];
I_new(:,:,3) = [zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)     I_temp(:,:,3) zeros(rows + (window_size - 1),additional_elements)];
cost = zeros(rows,cols);
for i = additional_elements + 1:rows
    for j = additional_elements+1:cols
        I_windowed(:,:,1) = I_new(i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,1);
        I_windowed(:,:,2) = I_new(i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,2);
        I_windowed(:,:,3) = I_new(i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,i-additional_elements:i+additional_elements,3);
        [unique_pixels_w,count_pixels_w] = countPixels(I_windowed);
        unique_pixels_w = setdiff(unique_pixels_w,[0 0 0],'rows');
        inside_segment = setdiff(unique_pixels,unique_pixels_w);
        outside_segments = setdiff(unique_pixels,inside_segment);
        area_segment = count_pixels_w;
        for k = 1:size(inside_pixels,1)
            current_segment = inside_segment(k,:);
            cost_curr_seg = sort(composition_cost(ismember(unique_pixels,current_segment,'rows'),:));
            for l = 1:size(cost_curr_seg,2)
                if(ismember(unique_pixels(l,:),outside_segments,'rows') && count_pixels(l) > 0)
                    composed_area = min(area_segment(k),count_pixels(l));
                    cost(i,j) = cost(i,j) + cost_curr_seg(l) * composed_area;
                    area_segment(k) = area_segment(k) - composed_area;
                    count_pixels(l) = count_pixels(l) - composed_area;
                    if area_segment(k) == 0
                        break
                    end
                end
            end
            if area(k) > 0
                cost(i,j) = cost(i,j) + max_apperance_distance *  area_segment(k);
            end
        end
    end
end

cost = cost / window_size;
```

The code for the countPixels function:

```
function [unique_rows,counts] = countPixels(I)
    [rows,cols,dims] = size(I);
    pixels_I = zeros(rows*cols,dims);
    count = 1;
    for i = 1:rows
        for j = 1:cols
            pixels_I(count,:) = reshape(I(i,j,:),[1,3]);
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end

    [unique_rows,~,ind] = unique(pixels_I,'rows');
    counts = histc(ind,unique(ind));
end
```

Comment: Could you post your current implementation? It will help a lot in finding ways to improve.

Comment: @mikkola I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ask the authors ! Usually they are kind enough to answer fast. And if they claim they did it in the paper they morally have to make it available. Worth a try !

Comment: @Ratbert Okay. I'll try. :)